# Use INT 13h/AH=2 to read kernel to memory above 1MB

Tags: linker, x86, kernel, disk

I am trying to load my kernel at 0x100000 which is the bottom of free space just after low memory.  The code I try using is:

```
mov dl, 0x80
xor bx, bx
mov cl, 3

pusha
mov es, bx
mov al, 128
mov bx, 0x8000
call readDisk

add bx, 0x0800

mov ecx, 9
.readSectors:
  add bx, 0x1000
  mov es, bx
  xor bx, bx
  mov al, 128
  call readDisk
  loop .readSectors

popa
```

Where my readDisk function is

```
readDisk:
pusha

mov ah, 0x02
mov ch, 0
mov dh, 0

int 0x13

jc disk_err:
popa
ret
```

Where disk_err prints an error message.

The idea behind this is that the segment of the address pointer changes which 
allows me to use segmenting to read 1MB into memory (0x100000).  The way the math worked out in my head was that by adding 0x1000 to bx each time, the segment increased by 0x10000 which is equivilent to 128 sectors (512 bytes each).  This done 9 times should read 64 more sectors than required to read 1MB into the disk.

The question is why doesn't this work?  When I run it in QEmu, the CPU triple faults when it reaches "jmp 0x100000" in long mode.  I did a little debugging by changing the jump location to 0x8000 which is the very next sector and I get the same result.  To me, this means that the CPU thinks I'm trying to jump to somewhere that doesn't exist indicating that my code which reads the disk up to 1MB isn't working correctly.

Addition:

I also tried starting my read disk at 0x100000 instead of trying to read all the sectors up to and beyond that point.  This looked like

```
pusha
mov bx, 0xff00
mov es, bx
xor bx, bx  ; address buffer is now 0xff00:0x1000
mov al, 10
call readDisk

popa

; switch to long mode down here.... I know this works

[bits 64]
LongMode:

jmp 0x100000

times 1048576 - ($-($$ + 512)) db 0
```

Comment: I tried a different approach setting es to 0xff00 and bx to 0x1000 which puts me at 0x100000 and upon reading 10 sectors I get the same result.  That is why I thought maybe I had to read sectors consecutively.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but if you set it to 0xFF00 and the first time through the loop you add 0x1000 to it that results in a value that can't be represented in a 16-bit register. The result would be 0x10F00 . The upper bit will be thrown away (the value wraps) and you end up  up with 0x0F00 .

Comment: Will you be going into protected mode at some point?

Comment: Up vote for 16bit x86 on so :) jmp 0x100000 does not make sense to me. It's larger than 16 bits. you need to set up cs and jump to 0?

Comment: Also, be aware or far vs. near jumps! It might not be obvious how to tell your assembler. http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_147.html

Comment: Right.  I was a bit misleading.  That jump is executed in long mode.  The code I posted is running in real mode.  I'll update the question.  Sorry for the confusion.  Also regarding Michael's first question, That segment was not the starting point for any loop.  In that attempt, I set al to 10 and set es:bx to 0xff00:0x1000 so I would start at 0x100000 and read the next 10 sectors.

Comment: You really need to show a minimal complete verifiable example.

Comment: Or just use a multiboot compliant bootloader like GrUB that loads a kernel at 0x100000 and enters protected mode. I don't know how big a kernel you are loading is but usually what people do if this is targeting a 386 is to put the CPU in [unreal mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode) then use int 0x13/ah=2 to read kernel data from disk a chunk at a  time to a fixed location in lower memory and then use 32-bit addressing (it iss allowed even in real mode) to copy the data loaded by the BIOS call up into memory >= 0x100000 .

Comment: The BIOS disk read interrupt is limited in the amount of memory above 1MB that it can address since the largest physical address value real mode supports is 0xFFFF:0xFFFF which is physical address (0xFFFF<<4)+0xFFFF = 0x10FFEF . This also assumes the A20 line is enabled. This is why you load it into lower memory with the BIOS interrupt for the disk read and then copy it to its final destination in the area above 0x100000.